# How to make a python script listen continuously in the background without raising an unknown value error

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I want to make a python script to run in the background continuously even if the user is not saying anything to it. Every time, when I try to do so, I get an unknown value error message. I  want the python script to listen continuously without giving any error. This the code that I am using:

```
import pyaudio 
import speech_recognition as sr

def callback(recognizer, audio):
# received audio data, now we'll recognize it using Google Speech        Recognition
try:

    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()
with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) 

stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

import time
for _ in range(100): time.sleep(0.1) 
stop_listening() 
print("over")
while True: time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the intended function of `while True: time.sleep(0.1)`? Same with the `for` loop. This just completely locks up your code.

Comment: Also, why do you do `for _ in range(100): time.sleep(0.1)` when you could do `time.sleep(10)`?

Comment: When I run the program and don't say anything to it, then it gives me an unknown value error. That error should not occur whether I say something to it or not.